# How do i export my ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I have created a sample ruby application which uses SQLite. Everything is working fine in my local machine.

Now I want to share this application, so everyone can download and deploy it in their own machines. So basically, I need to export my application along with its DB schema. I do not know how it is done. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

App is running on Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.4.3

Comment: There is no rails 4.4.3...

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a version control system like git combined with a repository like Github.com. There are other version control systems out there, but most people in the Rails community use git.

Comment: Also, the sqlite db doesn't need to be checked in, but if you use rails migrations, there should be a schema.rb file that documents the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use [github](http://github.com) for sharing your code (it's a version control system) and rails migrations for making sure your coders can be on the same database schema.